# TEXT -- disambiguate "m"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to figure out when "m" is month and when it is minute in Excel's `TEXT(...)` function? For example, the simplest example is `m/d` (month/day) as opposed to `m:s` (minute:second). How is this disambiguated in Excel?

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c

Comment: Basically, unless it is obvious that it is meant to be a time, `m:s`,`[m]`,`h:m` and so forth, it will default to month.  even `m:` will return the month followed by `:`

Comment: Is there a way... imho : `if m is there with d or y, its month. ,if m is there with s or h, its minute. `

Answer (score 1):

There is a note clarifying this the document [Number format codes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68), at the start of the section *Dates and times*

> **Important:** If you use the "m" or "mm" code immediately after the "h" or "hh" code (for hours) or immediately before the "ss" code (for seconds), Excel displays minutes instead of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to know...

imho : `if m is alone OR is there with d or y, its month. ,if m is there with s or h, its minute.`

Comment: for month you do not need the `d` or `y`.  It defaults to month.  `=TEXT(NOW(),"m")` will return the month.

Comment: add another if? [any more details the OP which part of "to figure out " that OP stuck with, this should answer the question I guess.. Or.. migrate the question to superuser.com perhaps]

Comment: I am just commenting on your `if m is there with d or y, its month`.  That is a little misleading.  outside of specifically stating it as a time `m` defaults to month.  It does not need a `d` or `y` reference.  `=TEXT(NOW(),"m")` will never bring minute, it will always assume month.

Comment: owh okes... got it.. Thanks for the heads up.. corrected. /(^_^)

Comment: Notice that the author of the question asked how to disambiguate, your answer is quite ambiguous. Also, if you base your answer in your opinion, it is subjective, and subjectivity causes ambiguity. Try to support your claims with examples. Also it seems to not be only coexistence, it depends on the order, e.g. what is the role of m in "dmh", both "d" and "h" are with m. How literal/escaped sequences affect the result? what about the .000 ?

Comment: Noted. Thanks. I understand that my post is a simple answer (not a comment). fwiw, does the the comment answers the ambiguity better? (if yes, i'm ok to remove this ans)